# Heroku App Errors on Missing Node Module (But It Looks Like It's Installed)

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I'm trying to get running with node and Heroku, but I've fallen at an early hurdle. Following [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#run-the-app-locally), I fail to see my Heroku app locally. Running

```
heroku local web
```

and going to localhost:5000 produces the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'ejs'

I've tried `npm install ejs -g` as suggested [here](http://tech-read.com/2013/05/09/node-js-500-error-cannot-find-module-ejs/) and it looks like that works `npm list -g --depth=0` shows that `ejs@2.3.4` is installed. What can I do to solve this curious error?

Comment: Did you try just removing `ejs` as a depency for now, to see if it starts normally without it (modify package.json)

Comment: @adeneo Yes that works. The page loads normally. I feel like I will need to `ejs` module eventually though if it is included as a dep in the tutorial. Do you have any ideas on how I could solve this more permanently? EJS looks to be just like underscore/lodash templating (if I'm not mistaken). Is it worth spending time trying to make it work or perhaps i just replace it.

Comment: I really like EJS, and use it all the time, and I hate Jade, but that's just me. The answer below could be on to something, but seeing as EJS is part of your depencies, all you should have to do is call `npm install` inside the directory you're using, and all depencies should be installed automagically.

Comment: @adeneo Yeah that was my understanding as well. I didn't think the `g` flag would cause any errors with `require`. I'm just curious, why do you dislike Jade over EJS, if you could sum it up in a few sentences.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm install -g` installs the package globally.

node cannot find globally installed packages when you reference them with

```
var ejs = require('ejs')
```

You need to install with `npm install --save ejs`.  This will install the package into the local `node_modules` directory and save it to your package.json

[This is because when node looks for a package](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders) where the path doesn't start with a `.` or a `/` it looks in the current directory's `node_modules` directory for a directory named after the package. Then it goes up a directory and does the same, keeping looping until it reaches the root of your file system.

e.g. if you're in `/users/thomas/src/myproject` it'll look for:

```
/users/thomas/src/myproject/node_modules/ejs
/users/thomas/src/node_modules/ejs
/users/thomas/node_modules/ejs
/users/node_modules/ejs
/node_modules/ejs
```

If it does not exist in one of those places, it will not be found.

([There are some deprecated ways](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders) that you can have it look in other places as well, but these are not recommended since it involves using an environment variable which can be difficult to remember to set on deployed machines)

Additionally if you're using heroku, you need to have the package listed in the `dependencies` of your package.json file in order for heroku to know to install it.  `npm install -g` does not add an entry to your package.json

Some recommendations, however.

1. Don't use EJS.  There are better (and currently maintained) templating packages out there.  We use EJS in an old legacy system and it's more frustrating than anything.
2. Don't ever install packages with -g unless you truly want the tool to be global. Most of the time you want it local to your project.

Comment: Thank you. I was only using `-g` as a sort of last resort. I had tried the normal `install ___ --save`, but couldn't understand why it wasn't working. Can you recommend a template that is less frustrating than EJS?

Comment: @thomas i've used handlebars and jade in a few projects and didn't mind using them. You might see which one supports your use-cases. If you still can't find the module after doing the `install` check all those paths or look for crazy errors in the npm install log?

Comment: Do I need to install a [log](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log), or is there a global npm log somewhere?

Comment: If npm fails at a task you'll get an `npm-debug.log` in the directory in which you ran the command. If there is none, you might try posting the code in which you're requiring `ejs` so we can see what else could be wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure why it worked this time, but installing at the project level fixed my issue. Thanks for all of your help!